# Google Maps changing placemark icon solely based on styleUrl string syntax

Tags: python, kml, simplekml

I've written a simple script in python that converts a CSV file to a KML file using the simplekml package. It colors my points based on one of my data values.

My problem is this: I’m trying to use the smallest icon possible because my placemarks are very close to each other. This works well when the style ID is “icon-1739-7CB342” but fails (Google My Maps renders a drop) when the style ID is “2”

The result is that the default KML generated by simplekml cannot be rendered with the small point as I cannot control the IDs.

My code:

```
import simplekml
import pandas
import sys

infile = sys.argv[1]
outfile = infile.split(".")[0]+".kml"


def genkml():
    kml = simplekml.Kml()
    ok = simplekml.Style()
    ok.iconstyle.color = 'ff42b37c'  # Green
    ok.iconstyle.icon.href = 'https://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png'
    ok.iconstyle.scale = 1

    rc = simplekml.Style()
    rc.iconstyle.color = 'ff00eaff'  # Yellow
    rc.iconstyle.icon.href = 'https://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png'
    rc.iconstyle.scale = 1

    seco = simplekml.Style()
    seco.iconstyle.color = 'ff0051e6'  # Red
    seco.iconstyle.icon.href = 'https://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png'
    seco.iconstyle.scale = 1
    
    df = pandas.read_csv(infile)
    cuenta = 1
    for lon, lat, desc in zip(df["longitude"], df["latitude"], df["desc"]):
        nogal = kml.newpoint()
        nogal.name = "Nogal"+"-"+str(cuenta)
        nogal.description = desc.upper()
        nogal.coords = [(lon, lat)]
        if "OK" in nogal.description:
            nogal.style = ok
        if "RC" in nogal.description:
            nogal.style = rc
        if "SECO" in nogal.description:
            nogal.style = seco
        cuenta += 1
    kml.save(outfile)
    print(kml.kml())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    genkml()
```

My test input file:

```
type,date time,latitude,longitude,accuracy(m),altitude(m),geoid_height(m),speed(m/s),bearing(deg),sat_used,sat_inview,name,desc
W,2021-05-30 21:08:27,28.66231833,-100.83812667,1,257.122,-23.722,0.000,,28,33,,Q31 ok
W,2021-05-30 21:11:56,28.66243667,-100.83811000,1,256.922,-23.722,0.000,,26,35,,O32 ok
```

The resulting KML (original):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
    xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
    <Document id="1">
        <Style id="2">
            <IconStyle id="3">
                <color>ff42b37c</color>
                <colorMode>normal</colorMode>
                <scale>1</scale>
                <heading>0</heading>
                <Icon id="4">
                    <href>https://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png</href>
                </Icon>
            </IconStyle>
        </Style>
        <Placemark id="12">
            <name>Nogal-1</name>
            <description>Q31 OK</description>
            <styleUrl>#2</styleUrl>
            <Point id="11">
                <coordinates>-100.83812667,28.66231833,0.0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark id="14">
            <name>Nogal-2</name>
            <description>Q32 OK</description>
            <styleUrl>#2</styleUrl>
            <Point id="13">
                <coordinates>-100.83811,28.66243667,0.0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

The modified KML, with a manually added style (ID = “icon-1739-7CB342”) that renders as a small dot for Nogal-2 and a drop for Nogal-1 (**please note that the only difference between the styles is the ID**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
    xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
    <Document id="1">
        <Style id="2">
            <IconStyle>
                <color>ff42b37c</color>
                <scale>1</scale>
                <Icon>
                    <href>https://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png</href>
                </Icon>
            </IconStyle>
        </Style>
        <Style id="icon-1739-7CB342">
            <IconStyle>
                <color>ff42b37c</color>
                <scale>1</scale>
                <Icon>
                    <href>https://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png</href>
                </Icon>
            </IconStyle>
        </Style>
        <Placemark id="12">
            <name>Nogal-1</name>
            <description>Q31 OK</description>
            <styleUrl>#2</styleUrl>
            <Point id="11">
                <coordinates>-100.83812667,28.66231833,0.0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark id="14">
            <name>Nogal-2</name>
            <description>Q32 OK</description>
            <styleUrl>#icon-1739-7CB342</styleUrl>
            <Point id="13">
                <coordinates>-100.83811,28.66243667,0.0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

[The rendered image by Google My Maps. I would like to use Nogal-2's icon without having to manually add the icon-1739-7CB342 style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJbOo.png)

Comment: Perhaps change the `<href>` to `https://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png` and scale it to be smaller.

Comment: Thank you @geocodezip. That's the URL I'm using in both cases, but the icons render differently.

Comment: @geocodezip even though scale is a float, I've tried a number <1 but it doesn't compare to the "dot" in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJbOo.png) for Nogal-2

Comment: Mean to type `http://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/959-wht-circle-blank.png` for the "dot" url in my comment above.

Comment: @geocodezip this renders a circle, but not as small as the dot (even with the smallest scale I could use of 0.4 or lower). It's a great suggestion, though. I'll use it if the ID issue is not demystified.

Comment: My guess on the id is that numeric IDs are not allowed (`The lexical domain (xsd:NCName) of this datatype **doesn't allow the definition of numerical identifiers** or identifiers containing whitespace.`, from [ref](http://books.xmlschemata.org/relaxng/ch19-77151.html)) by the schema.  Try adding a letter before the first number, or just using a letter.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your style ID(s) to start with a letter.  Per the XML spec (and therefore in KML), ID attributes cannot start with a number.  If that doesn't fix it, let us know and I can take a closer look at your KML.

Comment: Hi @Christiaan, the problem is that ID(s) are determined by simplekms. I went ahead and changed "2" with "icon-2", with same results. I have the impression that Google My Maps interprets the ID, but I haven't found any documentation supporting that. In previous tests the icon's color is rendered by the color code in the ID rather than the one in the color attribute. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you made sure to change ALL the IDs to not start with numbers, including the Document, Placemark and Point IDs?  I'm wondering if the xml parsing is failing part way through due to the IDs.  And I'm sure you've done this, but double check that you've updated the style IDs in both the Style tags and in the styleUrl tags that reference them.  Can you share an updated KML that still shows the issue?  Also, have you tried opening the KML in Google Earth Pro, and does it show the same issue?

Comment: Hi @Christiaan, Google Earth Pro shows the issue in a different way: The "icon-2" ID shows the drop, and the "icon-1739-7CB342"  ID shows a square with a red "X". The updated KML with all IDs starting with letters can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/cd58KP1E). Thanks for your help.